# xgboost: does it support stochastic gradient boosting?

Tags: boosting

What function/parameter needs to be set to enable stochastic gradient boosting in XGBoost?

I ask because in https://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/stobst.pdf, Jerome Friedman shows that stochastic gradient boosting outperforms regular gradient boosting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `subsample` parameter, which you can read about at xgboost's [read the docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) website.

Comment: Is subsampling performed independently at each iteration, so the algorithm uses a different subset of data for each tree? I feel from reading the doc the subsampling is performed only once at the very beginning, and the same subsampled data are used for every iteration.